# Ubuntu 20.04 - Second Monitor (HDMI port) is not recognized in

Tags: server, 20.04, nvidia, multiple-monitors

I am using an Acer Nitro AN515-44, which uses Ryzen 7 4000H and Nvidia GTX 1650Ti. The laptop was originally compatible for windows 10, but I am using now Ubuntu 20.04 with Linux kernel `5.15.0-69-generic`.

Current Nividia driver is  515.

[image: Nvidia Driver]

Then I bought an Acer monitor as I need dual monitors. I am trying to connect it, but my laptop is not even recognizing it.

I have tried changing the kernel to previous versions and also tried different Nvidia drivers.